# Combine Typescript method signatures with return type dependent on parameter value

Tags: typescript

If I have a return type that changes based on a parameter, how can I combine the method signatures?

```
function a1(verbose = true): VerbosePayload
function a2(verbose = false): NormalPayload
```

I would have thought one of the following might work

```
function a(verbose: boolean): typeof verbose extends true ? VerbosePayload : NormalPayload;
function a<T extends boolean>(verbose: T): T extends true ? VerbosePayload : NormalPayload;
```

but both error out. The obvious solution is to just break it into two methods, but I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to combine the two. It makes sense that Typescript errors here because `verbose` may not be known at compile time, but even an implementation such as

```
function a(verbose: boolean): typeof verbose extends true ? VerbosePayload : NormalPayload;
function a1() { a(true); }
function a2() { a(false); }
```

where `verbose` is known at compile time may be desirable to reduce duplicated code.

EDIT: following @katniss' advice, function overloading works. This example would look something like this:

```
function a(verbose: true): VerbosePayload;
function a(verbose: false): NormalPayload;
function a(verbose: boolean) { ... }
```

Comment: Why not use function overloads?

Comment: @katniss I was getting an error `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.` but after looking into it, it turned out to be an unrelated mistake on my part. Function overloading works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't (ab)use conditional types for this!](https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse.html)

Function overloads work:

```
function a(verbose: true): VerbosePayload;
function a(verbose: false): NormalPayload;
function a(verbose: boolean) { ... }
```

However, calling `a` with something of type `boolean` (not the literal types `true`/`false`) now results in an error. If you don't want that, then just add a third overload and make sure it's last since overloads are matched in the order they are defined.

```
function a(verbose: true): VerbosePayload;
function a(verbose: false): NormalPayload;
function a(verbose: boolean): VerbosePayload | NormalPayload;
function a(verbose: boolean) { ... }
```